# Permutation of array elements, as a query criteria in MongoID querying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I've got an "[embedded one to many](http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/embedded/1-n.html)" model like the following:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :nickname
  embeds_many :watchlists
end

class Watchlist
 include Mongoid::Document

 field :html_url
 field :description
 field :tags_array, type: Array
 embedded_in :user
end
```

and a "[criteria](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html)" for querying like the following :

```
User.where('watchlists.tags_array' => %w[ruby web framework])
```

The problem is that it match just the "exact" sequence of words presented by 'watchlists.tags_array', while I want it to match all the permutations of 'ruby', 'web' and 'framework'.

Ex.:

in case of array like: %w[ruby web framework], I need a match for all the following permutations:

```
ruby web framework
ruby framework web

framework web ruby 
framework ruby web

web framework ruby
web ruby framework
```

Is that possible ? How can I do that ?

UPDATE:

query was a bit more complex (I was trying to semplify), it a nested kind of extraction and permutation doesn't work with either my solution nor with Sergio Tulentsev solution. It just match the exact array in both the cases:

```
  Object.const_set :Competitor, Struct.new(:html_url, :description, :watchers, :forks)
  def self.find_competitors(tags_array)
    competitors = []
    # doesn't work:  User.where('watchlists.tags_array' => tags_array).only(:watchlists).each do |u|
    User.all_in('watchlists.tags_array' => tags_array).only(:watchlists).each do |u|
      u.watchlists.where(:tags_array => tags_array).each do |wl|
        competitors << Competitor.new(wl.html_url, wl.description, wl.watchers, wl.forks)
      end
    end
    return competitors
  end
```

UPDATE:

I just miss, the same '[all_in criteria](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#all_in)' into the inner cicle too ... and permutation works fine too :

```
User.all_in('watchlists.tags_array' => tags_array).only(:watchlists).each do |u|
  u.watchlists.all_in(:tags_array => tags_array).each do |wl|
    competitors << Competitor.new(wl.html_url, wl.description, wl.watchers, wl.forks)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `$all` operator

```
db.users.find({'watchlists.tags_array': { $all: ['ruby', 'web', 'framework']}});
```

In [Mongoid speak](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#all_in) it should be this:

```
User.all_in('watchlists.tags_array' => %w[ruby web framework])
```

Comment: I just needed, same 'all_in' into the inner cicle too ... thanks Sergio.